# How to programmatically change password of a saved wifi network in Android (API level 23, Android 6.0)

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

**Premise:**

I'm currently work on an Android App (API level 23, Android 6.0) that connect with a device via Wi-Fi and uses UDP packets to communicate. I'm able to change the device Wi-Fi password using a particular command. This works fine.

**Target:**

What I'm tring to programmatically do is:

1. search Wi-Fi generated from the device
2. connect to the device
3. send the command to change the password
4. reconnect to the device using the new password

I'm able to connect the first time (steps 1,2,3) using code like this:

```
private void connect(String ssid, String password) {
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    conf.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password);
    netId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    mWifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    mWifiManager.disconnect();
    mWifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    mWifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

**Additional info:**

In the Manifest file I declared these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**The problem:**

If I try to use the same method to connect after the change of the password, I'm not able to achive the connection because (I think) Android remembers the previous password.

If I try to use `updateNetwork(conf)` instead of `addNetwork(conf)`, I don't notice any difference.

I've tried to remove or disable in some ways the saved network before try to connect again, but unsaccesfully.

```
mWifiManager.removeNetwork(netId)
```

returns false (I have no idea why it fails)

```
mWifiManager.disableNetwork(netId);
```

returns true but it appears to have no effects

If I use the Android settings to change password, all works fine... but I want to change the saved password programmatically.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Do you have the `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permission declared in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to add this info

Comment: @Lipsyor I am also facing same issue, I added CHANGE_WIFI_STATE and enable location permission. Did you got any solution for change password?

Comment: @Teja see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several attempts, I currently have no problems following the instructions I report below.

Before connecting to a Wi-Fi network it is important to check the list of previously saved networks. If there is no network with the same SSID it is possible to create a new configuration, otherwise it is necessary to modify the existing one.

```
public void connect(String ssid, String password) {

    WifiConfiguration wifiConf = null;
    WifiConfiguration savedConf = null;

    //existing configured networks
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = mWifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

    if(list!=null) {
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "existing network found: " + i.networkId + " " + i.SSID);
                savedConf = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(savedConf!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "coping existing configuration");
        wifiConf = savedConf;
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "creating new configuration");
        wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
    }

    wifiConf.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    wifiConf.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password);

    int netId;

    if(savedConf!=null) {
        netId = mWifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConf);
        Log.d(TAG, "configuration updated " + netId);
    } else {
        netId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConf);
        Log.d(TAG, "configuration created " + netId);
    }

    mWifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    mWifiManager.disconnect();
    mWifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    mWifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

Comment: `mWifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConf);` returning -1, althought the savedConf was not null. Any idea?

Comment: Okay it's strange but I have to explicitly set network id to wifiConf again before calling update.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar addNetwork() will return -1 if the password length is less than 8 chars or if network is already in the configured list. Therefore use updateNetwork() for already configured networks and make sure password length is min 8 chars

Comment: @MuhammadBabar So you are setting new networkId on already configured network ?

Comment: Note: You can only make changes to the configured networks if your app has created them, not the ones added by other apps or by wifi system app.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-network

Comment: @rd7773 Yeah I know about the restrictions on Marshmallow but my app targetSdk is 22.

Comment: @rd7773 No I was updating it please check my comment above for the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Android after version 6 does not allow any application to modify Wi-Fi networks unless it has been created by the application itself. In addition, it does not allow adding Wi-Fi networks with the same name as others already configured previously. This is very curious because when you configure Wi-Fi networks manually from the settings, it does allow it.
After thinking for a long time about a possible solution it occurred to me that perhaps the Wifi network could be added with another name and once added, change it to the desired name. I have tried it and it works. It would be something like the following:

```
int networkId = -1;

// Find my Wifi
List<WifiConfiguration> configuredWifis = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for(WifiConfiguration wifi : configuredWifis)
{
    if(wifi.SSID != null && wifi.SSID.equals("\"" + WIFI_SSID + "\"") && wifi.priority == WIFI_PRIORITY)
    {
        networkId = wifi.networkId;
    }
    else
    {
        wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifi.networkId);
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifi.networkId); // After android 6 it really does not remove the Wifi network
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    }
}


if(networkId == -1)
{
    // If my Wifi is not yet configured then add it
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + WIFI_SSID + "\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ WIFI_PASSW +"\"";
    conf.priority = WIFI_PRIORITY;
    networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    if(networkId == -1) // This ocurs when a wifi with the same name is yet configured. After Android 6 is not possible modify it.
    {
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int randomInteger = random.nextInt(10000);
        conf.SSID = "\"" + WIFI_SSID + randomInteger + "\"";
        networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf); // Add my wifi with another name
        conf.SSID = "\"" + WIFI_SSID + "\"";
        conf.networkId = networkId;
        networkId = wifiManager.updateNetwork(conf); // After my wifi is added with another name, I change it to the desired name
    }
}

// Connect to my wifi
if(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId() != networkId)
{
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting trick. I think is very important to delete every previously created network before adding a new one. Otherwise the list of saved network will increase at every connection.